# What's the reason for sql-updates being triggered multiple times?

Tags: sql

When an existing extension is updated either manually or using Magento-Connect, in some occasions the sql-updates are triggered multiple times right away or again after a short while, although the version is correctly saved in the table "core_resource".

Comment: Have you been able to pinpoint the 'some occasions'? Is it only on certain extensions or all? Does it only happen on one particular site/setup?

Comment: Are you also using multiple web servers?

Comment: ahh, good idea :) If the version in the database is too low, the setup script is triggered, if the setup is not fast enough (or the next request too fast) the setup is triggered twice. But this shouldn't happen again after this first run.

Comment: @FlorinelChis it's a one server setup

Comment: @Fooman we found out that the update is only triggered with a specific category url that includes some filters i.e. "specialoffers.html?frontend_color_filter=187&season_filter=169&shoe_size_eu=31&dir=asc&order=position&price=1%2C100"

Only when this url was called, the update script was triggered again for a few days.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt yes that is possible, but you can prevent that by setting the site in maintenance mode. That's what we did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comment @benmarks.
The version in the config.xml and database were the same and all updates were executed correctly.

The reason was an corrupt mysql-table.
We executed an "REPAIR TABLE" and "OPTIMIZE TABLE" and the problem was solved.

Thanks everyone for the support.

Answer (score 4):

This is only possible when the configuration object contains a version number higher than the version number in the database. Therefore, there is either an error in the script which is causing the version number to not update (which is reportedly *not* the case), or there is a stale bit of information coming from the database, or... something else which can likely be debugged in [`Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyUpdates()` (link)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php#L299).